# ERROR: Method 'methodName' not defined in Plugin 'plugin' - Phonegap 3.0 iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm trying to develop an iOS App using phonegap 3.0. 
The app uses sharekit plugin and GAPlugin for phonegap, and it was working when I was using phonegap 2.9
After the upgrade it compiles and when I try to access the functions in the plugin, it gives me this error.

```
ERROR: Method 'share:' not defined in Plugin 'ShareKitPlugin'
2013-07-22 22:05:06.976  -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "INVALID",
  "ShareKitPlugin",
  "share",
  [
    "test",
    "http:\/\/www.test.com"
  ]
]

ERROR: Method 'initGA:' not defined in Plugin 'GAPlugin'
2013-07-22 22:05:06.977 -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "GAPlugin1900170756",
  "GAPlugin",
  "initGA",
  [
    "UA-XXXXXX-11",
    10
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you tru use "old" plugin in phonegap 3.0 you should write hack in native code of plugin method. For example:

```
- (void)register:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    self.callbackId = command.callbackId;
    NSArray *arguments = command.arguments;
    NSDictionary *options = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
```

instead of

```
- (void)register:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options
    self.callbackId = [arguments pop];
```

Comment: finally, after spending almost a day with the problem - this solved it. thx

Answer (score 7):

The GAPlugin does not yet support the new Plugin signature that Phonegap introduced in 2.1.0. The old plugin signature is no longer supported in Phonegap/Cordova 3.0.0.

The new signature is:

```
- (void)myMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
```

The GAPlugin still uses:

- (void) initGA:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

(see https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/GAPlugin.h for more details).

The same seems to apply for the ShareKit plugin.

Comment: Thank you floerkem I've updated both the plugins  accordingly and it's working

Answer (score 2):

Based on Floerkem's answer I've modified both the plugins

GAPlugin here https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin/issues/16 
ShareKitPlugin here https://github.com/mohamedfasil/ShareKitPlugin-for-Phonegap-3.0